# redirect - Redirecting to previous page after login?

Tags: php, mysql

I need someone's expertise. Once the user is logged in.... I want them to be redirected to another php page if they attempt to go back to the login page. Right now my user can still login but also is able to go back to the login form.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

session_start();

$password = $_POST['pass'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$user_pass= md5($user_pass);

$check_user = "select * from userss where user_pass='$password' AND user_email='$email'";

$run = mysql_query($check_user);

if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){

$_SESSION['email']=$email;

echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
}
else {
echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect!')</script>";
   }

}

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

This type of question has already been answered. See [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

You are already be checking the login status of your user prior to serving any page. Right?

```
if (logged_in){
  header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
  die();
}
```

Comment: *This type of question has already been answered* Why do you then post an answer? You can vote for close as dupe/ write a comment/ flag it to get closed

Comment: I'm new to the site... I know the answer was probably answered but since I'm a newb with coding, I thought maybe if I place my code down, I could get a better answer

Answer (score 0):

try this.

this processlogin.php write this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    session_start();
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $user_pass= md5($user_pass); 
    $check_user = "select * from userss where user_pass='$password' AND user_email='$email'";
    $run = mysql_query($check_user);
    if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){ 
        $_SESSION['email']=$email; 
        echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
    } else { 
        echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect!')</script>"; 
    } 
}
```

in login.php write  this code:

```
    <?php 
if(session_start()){
       echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
    }else{ ?>
       <form method='post' action='processlogin.php' class="form-signin">
           <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login </h2>
           <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only"></label>
           <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus><br>
           <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only"></label>
           <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required><br/>
           <button type="submit">LOGIN</button>
       </form>
    <?php } ?>
```

hope this can help.

Comment: I should replace the script and add the login.php code?

Comment: copy my code to your loginform.php , and your code in loginform,php move to " else{   //here     }  ".

Comment: loginform.php i mean is file of to create view your login form.

which contains:
<form>  
    username : <input type="text" name="username"/>
    password : <input type="password" name="password"/>
</form>

Comment: can i have your login form code ? and i'll edit my answer, so that you understand.

Comment: <?php


if(isset($_POST['login'])){
 session_start();

 $password = $_POST['pass'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 
 $user_pass= md5($user_pass);
 
 $check_user = "select * from userss where user_pass='$password' AND user_email='$email'";
 
 $run = mysql_query($check_user);
 
 if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){
 
 $_SESSION['email']=$email;
 
 
 echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
 }
 else {
 echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect!')</script>";
 }
 

}
 


?>

Comment: <form method='post' action='login.php' class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login </h2>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only"></label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="Email address" required autofocus><br>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only"></label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

Comment: check my edited answer.

if my answer helpful please vote up and mark it as accepted. it will increase your reputation.

Comment: open localhost/yourappname/login.php  . is still not working bro ?

Comment: I'm using Linux/cPanel.... no its not working.... I just don't want the user to be able to return to login page once successfully logged in.

Comment: just add condition in login page  if(session_start()){ redirect to home  }  .